# Matrices in R: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r

I'm trying to initialize an empty matrix X with n rows and 4 columns. And then allocating a vector of random stock values to each column. Each column represents a different stock.

I know I should apply X[,i]=cumsum(X[,i]) eventually, to get actual stock values, but that can only be done after allocating the values in the first place.

```
#Inputs mean return, volatility, time period and time step
mu=0.25; sigma=2; T=1; n=2^(12); X0=5;
#Generating trajectories for stocks
#NOTE: Seed is fixed. Changing seed will produce 
#different trajectories
dt=T/n
t=seq(0,T,by=dt)
set.seed(201)


X <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 4)

for(i in 1:4){
  X[,i] <- c(X0,mu*dt+sigma*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=1))

}
```

After running the code, I get the error message:

```
Error in X[, i] <- c(X0, mu * dt + sigma * sqrt(dt) * rnorm(n, mean = 0,  : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: If you look at `length(c(X0,mu*...))`, you'll see that it is returning `2^12 + 1` elements, not the required `2^12`. Are you trying to change the size of the matrix dynamically? (That isn't going to work.)

Comment: To figure this out: (1) start with a much smaller size, say `n=12`; (2) run your code until it fails (nothing new here); (3) see that `i` is 1, meaning it fails first pass (in other troubleshooting, that may not always be true); (4) run *without assignment* your `c(X0,mu*...)` vector, and note that it is returning 13 elements, not 12 (as defined by `n`).

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the explanation! Initializing the matrix with n+1 rows works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm glad that works, but ... why not just omit `X0` from the loop? It's constant, so can be very easily be added post-`for`-loop with `rbind(5, X)`.

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure. It was just intuitive since the starting value is X0 for a stock and the rest are deviations as time goes on. Is there any advantage to doing it the way you suggest?

btw is there a way I can name my columns in the matrix Stock 1, Stock 2....till Stock 100?

Comment: The prepending of `X0` each time is just an efficiency thing, in that context it might make sense to keep it there as "declarative code". As far as naming ... `colnames(X) <- c("Stock1", "Stock2", ...)` or `colnames(X) <- paste0("Stock", seq_len(ncol(X)))`?

Comment: Thank you again. I just starting using R last week, and I think I have the basics down but still there so many functions like paste0() that I have never even seen